# Different rendering of European characters on two pages of same site with same charset

Tags: html, character-encoding, internationalization, meta-tags

I have a site which is supposed to show French, Spanish characters. There is this strange situation where two pages handle it completely differently.

Both pages share the same header file where I use this **meta tag**:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

I also set the charset at the global level in **IIS > MIME Types**:

```
.asp   text/html; charset=iso-8859-1   local
```

The pages are http://aer2.es/fr/ and http://aer2.es/fr/method

What could be the reason for this inconsistency?

Comment: Needs more info. Where does the data on the second page come from?

Comment: @Pekka The data is in the .asp file. Not coming from database. Same for both pages.

Comment: Then the second page's source code is probably encoded as UTF-8, can you check in your IDE's settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The physical encoding of the other file is in UTF-8, instead of Windows-1252 (ANSI, ISO-8859-1 ... + other mislabelings you see fit)

You can fix it by opening the other file, for example, in notepad, hitting save as, and choosing  `"ANSI"` from the Encoding dropdown menu and then using the new saved file.

---

Another way to do it is to change the meta tag in the other page to `UTF-8`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

however, when saving the change, you need to ensure that you are saving the file in UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: I'd suggest to fix by moving all the code to UTF-8 rather than ISO, but you got a point.

Comment: @PawełDyda Of course, but it might not be that simple if everything is so far configured Windows-1252.

Comment: As the other file is apparently in UTF-8, and looks good in a browser if the encoding is manually set to UTF-8, and as the HTTP headers do not specify an encoding, there is alternative, simple fix: change the name of the encoding in a `meta` tag from iso-8859-1 to utf-8.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela That's just as valid and would be a quick fix yes, but as he saves that file to have `utf-8` in the meta tag, it could be saved as ANSI (because he doesn't know that an encoding should be specified in the first place) and he would be back at square one. I mean, this is thinking that he has cp1252 as default, and got the utf-8 file from someone else or something.